# Command available at terminal prompt, but nowhere to be found

Tags: linux, filesystems, command, find, locate

This is puzzling. I can use the **module** command at the terminal prompt, but I can't find where the executable is located in the file system! I did the three following searchs:

1- *which module* returns "no module in ...",

2- searched *module* under the bin/ directories of the PATH variable ... nothing,

3- *locate module | grep -e "/module$"* ...nothing.

None of these searches gave me the location! Suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **module** perhaps set as an alias? You could try this:

```
type -a module
```

Comment: I got module is a function :)
module () 
{ 
    eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}
I can't find the function in /etc/bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, and ~/.bashrc

Comment: I finally found it under /usr/share/Modules/init/bash called by /etc/profile.d/modules.sh  A million thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion:

```
find / -name "module*"
```

As root